# Regex on array of chars in python?

Tags: python, arrays, regex, ctypes

I have a buffer (an array of chars) that I am using to read data in from a socket, which contains an HTTP request. I have some regular expressions that work nicely for extracting relevant info from strings, and I am looking for a way to use those regular expressions to extract the same info from an array instead, without having to build a string out of the array. Is this possible with ctypes? This is an example of how I am getting the data right now.

```
import socket, array, ctypes
libc = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('libc.so.6')
buff = array.array('c', '\0'*4096)
a, b = socket.socketpair()
fd = a.fileno()
buff_pointer = buff.buffer_info()[0]
b.send('a'*100)
bytes_read = libc.recv(fd, buff_pointer, len(buff), 0)
print buff #prints a zeroed array of length 4096 with 100 chars of 'a' in front
```

This is purely for fun/for lulz btw, inb4 it's unpythonic.

Comment: Dunno if it's officially supported, but when I try it, `re` seems to support searching in anything that supports the buffer interface. That includes `array.array` instances.

Comment: Alternatively, `buff = bytearray(4096); bytes_read = a.recv_into(buff)`.

Comment: @eryksun yeah, I am aware of that method, I am just using ctypes for kicks.

Comment: @user2357112 Cool I will try this out. I think I just have to make sure the object I am using as an expression is the same type as the object I am trying to match against.

Comment: @user2357112 no this doesn't work on any type that supports the buffer interface, the re module expects the objects to be hashable as well. Arrays aren't hashable because they are mutable, I believe.

Comment: OK, then I suggest using a ctypes array such as `buff = (ctypes.c_char * 4096)()`. Then you don't have to get `buff_pointer`, unless you're doing that for fun, too.

Comment: The **pattern** needs to be hashable because `re` caches them.

Answer (score 1):

Just run your regexs on the array object, e.g.

```
>>> import re
>>> m = re.match('^aaaaa', buff)
>>> m
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7fd4cd2cd030>
>>> m.group()
array('c', 'aaaaa')
>>> m.string[m.start():m.end()]
array('c', 'aaaaa')
```

etc...

Comment: Yes, the _sre extension module should work on any contiguous `char` or `wchar_t` buffer . See [`getstring`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3a1db0d2747e/Modules/_sre.c#l1686) in _sre.c.

Comment: Wide characters are 4 bytes on most POSIX builds, so you can use a buffer with either single-byte elements or four-byte elements. Wide characters are 2 bytes on Windows. `re` factors the character size into its iteration and pattern matching: `re.match(b'ab', (ctypes.c_uint32 * 2)(97, 98)).group() == [97, 98]`.